Where is the mistake in this proof that 2-form is non-vanishing?
Suppose $F : \mathbb{R}^3 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is $C^{\infty}$ and that $0$ is a regular value, so that $M = F^{-1}(0)$ is a $2$-dimensional submanifold of $\mathbb{R}^3$. The goal is to prove that $dx \wedge dy$ is non-vanishing on $M$ when $dF/dz \neq 0$. I know this can be done very easily be choosing the obvious slice-chart for the submanifold allowing us to conclude that when $dF/dz \neq 0$, $(x, y)$ is an admissible local coordinate system. However, I want to try doing this proof without "picking a chart" (explicitly).
I think one can argue via the standard implicit function theorem that for some $p \in M$ for which $dF/dz \neq 0$, there is a neighbourhood $V$ and a smooth $g : V \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ such that $F(x, y, g(x, y)) = 0$. Thus, we can define smooth $G : V \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^3$ with image in $M$ as $G(x, y) = (x, y, g(x, y))$, and since $M$ is a (regular) submanifold, $G$ considered as a map into $M$ (which we will always do going forward) is smooth. Let $i : M \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^3$ be inclusion, it is easy to see that $(i \circ G)_{*} = i_{*} \circ G_{*}$ is injective on $V$, so $G_{*}$ must be injective, and since $T_{(x_0, y_0)} V$ and $T_p M$ have the same dimension, this is an isomorphism. If we let $\partial_x, \partial_y$ be a basis for $T_{(x_0, y_0)} V$ and pushforward to a basis $G_{*} \partial_x$, $G_{*} \partial y$ for $T_p M$, then we can see that
$$(dx \wedge dy)(G_{*} \partial_x, G_{*} \partial y) = \partial_x(x \circ i \circ G) \partial_y(y \circ i \circ G) = 1$$
so the form is non-vanishing.
My question: where did I go wrong? This feels far too complicated. I think I'm likely missing a very obvious way to arrive at this result quicker...

What is the two form $dx\wedge dy$? If it’s the pull back of $dx\wedge dy$ via the inclusion map, I don’t think this is true. Consider the two sphere given by the vanishing locus of $x^2+y^2+z^2-1$, then there are points where the tangent space is spanned $\partial_z$ and $\partial_y$, namely the point $(1,0,0)$,  so $dx\wedge dy$ vanishes at a point.

Yes, it's the pullback of $dx \wedge dy$. I'm talking about points where $dF/dz \neq 0$ exclusively, at $(1, 0, 0)$, we have $dF/dz = 2z = 0$ @Chris

I'm a bit lost on what you're trying to do in the second paragraph. By asserting the existence of $g$, you've shown that $G\vert_M^{-1}$ is a coordinate chart on $M$, and so defines local coordinates $(x,y)$ on $M$. Then clearly $dx\wedge dy$ is non-vanishing on $M$.

By $G|_M^{-1}$, I assume you mean $G^{-1} : G(V) \rightarrow V$? I would agree, but we don't know that $G(V)$ is open at this point in the proof, so I don't see how you can immediately say it is a coordinate chart. @user17945

Yes, I mean that (sorry, miswrote it). You've acknowledged at this point in the proof that $G:V\to M$ is smooth, so why would you doubt that $G(V)$ is open?

I guess because we don't know that $G$ has invertible differential at this stage in the proof, so we can't just use inverse function theorem (yet) But I do say this on the next line, so I guess I could have stopped here @user17945

Well, whenever you're using the implicit function theorem, you're essentially using the inverse function theorem. And the former is used in two places here - one in asserting that $F^{-1}(0)$ is an embedded submanifold (it's part of the proof of the regular value theorem), and one in asserting the existence of $g$. Maybe this is the confusion?

Yep, that's true, thanks!

Comment: One way to do this without using any parameterization (coordinates) on $M$ is to observe the following: If $p \in M$ and $\partial_zF(p) \ne 0$, then the vectors $$ v_1 = (\partial_zF(p),0,-\partial_xF(p)),\ v_2 = (0,\partial_zF(p),-\partial_yF(p)) $$
form a basis of $T_pM$. It is easy to check that $$ (dx\wedge dy)(v_1,v_2) \ne 0. $$

I also want to note that it is useful to be able to figure out whether a problem in differential geometry like this can be answered using only linear algebra or whether something from analysis or calculus, such as the implicit function theorem is needed.
This question is a good example of one where only linear algebra is needed.

@Deane After reading your comment,I see that Jack was trying to show that $i_M^(dx\wedge dy)\ne 0$, while I thought he was trying to show that $G_(dx\wedge dy)\ne 0$ (or equivalently, that $(x,y)$ are good coordinates on $M$). I see now this was clarified in the first comment, but I think that was posted while I was writing mine.

Suppose that $v=(x_1,y_1,z_1)$ and $w=(x_2,y_2,z_2)$ both lie in $T_pF^{-1}(0)\subset \mathbb R^3$ such that at $p$ we have $dF/dz\neq0$. Then we have that:
\begin{align}
 (dF/dx)x_1+(dF/dy)y_1+(dF/dz)z_1=0\qquad\text{and}\qquad (dF/dx)x_2+(dF/dy)y_2+(dF/dz)z_2=0
\end{align}
So we need to find $v$ and $w$ such that the above holds and:
\begin{align}
x_1-y_2\neq0
\end{align}
Note that if $dF/dx=dF/dy=0$, then we can choose any element of the form $v=(a,b,0)$ and $w=(c,d,0)$ such that $a\neq d$. If $dF/dx=0$ but $dF/dy\neq 0$ then we can choose $v=(0,dF/dz,-dF/dy)$ and any $w$, and similarly for $dF/dx\neq 0$ and $dF/dy=0$. There is only one case left to check and that is $dF/dx\neq 0$ and $dF/dy\neq 0$. In that we can choose $v=(0,dF/dZ,-dF/dY)$, and $w=(-dF/dy\cdot dF/dz,1/2dF/dz\cdot dF/dx,1/2dF/dx\cdot dF/dz)$. At each point where $dF/dz\neq 0$, there are then vectors such that $dx\wedge dy(v,w)\neq 0$ so it doesn't vanish.
There might be a better way to do this without cases, but this is how I thought of it.
